# nothing provides requested tasks 2.8.0 when install python tasks requirement

Tags: python-3.x

Now I want to add `tasks` requirement into my python project, first step i add the [tasks](https://pypi.org/project/tasks/) dependencies into the `requirement.txt`:

```
tasks=2.8.0
```

then I try to run this command to install the requirement:

```
mamba install --file requirements.txt
```

the log shows like this:

```
~/source/pydolphin on  feature/celery! ⌚ 11:40:06
$ mamba install --file requirements.txt                                                                                               ‹ruby-2.7.2›

                  __    __    __    __
                 /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \
                /    \/    \/    \/    \
███████████████/  /██/  /██/  /██/  /████████████████████████
              /  / \   / \   / \   / \  \____
             /  /   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \__,
            / _/                       \_____/  `
            |/
        ███╗   ███╗ █████╗ ███╗   ███╗██████╗  █████╗
        ████╗ ████║██╔══██╗████╗ ████║██╔══██╗██╔══██╗
        ██╔████╔██║███████║██╔████╔██║██████╔╝███████║
        ██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██║██║╚██╔╝██║██╔══██╗██╔══██║
        ██║ ╚═╝ ██║██║  ██║██║ ╚═╝ ██║██████╔╝██║  ██║
        ╚═╝     ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝     ╚═╝╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝

        mamba (0.15.1) supported by @QuantStack

        GitHub:  https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba
        Twitter: https://twitter.com/QuantStack

█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████


Looking for: ['feedparser==6.0.2', 'requests==2.25.1', 'bs4==4.9.3', 'beautifulsoup4==4.9.3', 'psycopg2==2.8.6', 'numpy==1.20.2', 'maya==0.6.1', 'sqlalchemy==1.4.6', 'redis==5.0.3', 'croniter==0.3.36', 'apscheduler==3.7.0', 'opencv==4.5.2', 'mamba==0.15.1', 'celery==5.1.2', 'tasks==2.8.0']

conda-forge/osx-64       Using cache
conda-forge/noarch       Using cache
pkgs/main/noarch         [====================] (00m:00s) No change
pkgs/r/osx-64            [====================] (00m:00s) No change
pkgs/main/osx-64         [====================] (00m:00s) No change
pkgs/r/noarch            [====================] (00m:02s) Done

Pinned packages:
  - python 3.9.5


Encountered problems while solving:
  - nothing provides requested tasks 2.8.0

(pydolphin)
```

the log shows error message: `nothing provides requested tasks 2.8.0`. why would this happen and what should I do to fix the problem and install tasks success? BTW, this is my full dependencies of my project:

```
feedparser=6.0.2
requests=2.25.1
bs4=4.9.3
beautifulsoup4=4.9.3
psycopg2=2.8.6
numpy=1.20.2
maya=0.6.1
sqlalchemy=1.4.6
redis=5.0.3
croniter=0.3.36
apscheduler=3.7.0
opencv=4.5.2
mamba=0.15.1
celery=5.1.2
tasks=2.8.0
```

I have searched from internet but seems no one encount this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Mamba` is conda-like package manager and needs compatible packages. The `tasks` is a `pip` package and ATM nobody has created recipe for `conda`/`mamba` for the `tasks` package. Because there is no recipe for that package, you are told that the package is not `provided` in channels you searched in (those were "conda-forge", "pkgs/main"...).

Solution:

Correct (recomended): Write a `conda` recipe for `tasks` and either use it locally, or create your channel on anaconda cloud or upload in to some public channel (This may take a while, as there is usually review process involved).

Punk (not recomended): Install your requirements except the `tasks` and then use `pip` to install the `tasks`. Note, that the changes made by pip to the `env` are not tracked by the `mamba` package manager. More info on the topic https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment.

Notes:
Search in public conda packages on anaconda cloud like this: `https://anaconda.org/search?q=tasks`